# Highstock tooltip.positioner isn t working

Tags: position, tooltip, highcharts

I can t change the position of tooltip in highcharts:

```
    tooltip: {
    positioner: function() {
        return {
            x: 20,
            y: 20
        };
    }},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e07s2oq6/

Doc:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.positioner

I want to change the tooltip like this:

[image]

Comment: I can see what you see, if you want the tooltip in a fixed position, you can set `split: false` for tooltips. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split. That makes it appear at your x, y coordinates.

Comment: Doc you are referring is for  highcharts ,check https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.positioner for highstock this will  help

Comment: yes, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly solution that solves your problem.

I set the tool-tip positioner to the following:

```
tooltip: {
  split: false,
  positioner: function() {
    return {
      x: this.now.anchorX - this.label.width/2,
      y: 20
    };
  }
},
```

Now it shows a tool-tip centered above the point that is being hovered.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/e07s2oq6/3/

Comment: for some reason, just setting split to false made it work.